# How to disable only one radio-box when using *ngFor in template Driven Forms

Tags: angular, radio-button, ngfor, disable

i would like to disable a radio-button input when a condition is true. The form is generated with a *ngFor and it is a template driven form.
The condition is only true once, but all radio-buttons are disabled. Why?
How can I fix this, so that only the radio-button gets disabled, where the condition is true.

```
<form #haushaltsForm="ngForm" (submit)="submit(haushaltsForm.value)" novalidate *ngIf="haushaltsdaten">
  <div class="container" *ngFor="let haushaltsdata of haushaltsdaten">
    <div class="radio">
      <input
        [disabled]="haushaltsdata.status === 'xy'"
        class="radiobox" id="{{haushaltsdata.kundenNummer}}"
        type="radio"
        value="{{haushaltsdata.vorname}}"
        name="status"
        [(ngModel)]="value">
      <label for="{{haushaltsdata.kundenNummer}}">
        <div>{{haushaltsdata.vorname}} {{haushaltsdata.nachname}}</div>
      </label>
      {{haushaltsdata.registrierungsstatus == 'VOLLSTAENDIG'}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <button [disabled]="!value" type="submit">Show Person</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This looks like a problem with `haushaltsdaten`, if truly only one `haushaltsdata.status === 'xy'` then only that one would disable

Comment: I have cheked it. When showing  it in the HTML: {{ haushaltsdata.status === 'xy'}}, it shows true false false, but all are disabled.

Comment: What's the `novalidate` directive? I just created minimal reproduction and it works as expected

Can you create a stackblitz please?